# run android background task in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-native-module

I want to create an ability in my `react-native` android app to send my user `geolocation` to the server for each period of time, even if he closed the app!
so probably it means i have to run some thing like a task for run on Os(android) from a `NativeModule`.(and you can recommend better solution if you have).

but after spending many time on searching i have not found any example of creating a job or process which can keep running if app closed.  can any body give some clue about it ?

**Update:** i can ask my question like this to: how can i run a process for keep execute if app has closed in react native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to use this for location purposes, I would suggest you to use a library, 
https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation

I have used it in few apps, it gets the job done, And it will save you the time to write a native module for both android as well as ios.
Or if you don't want to use it for location purpose, you can use `headless js`,

Comment: does this component keep working even if app has closed??

Comment: yes, on android...on ios it will work for foreground.

Comment: You'r right ... but i have a mad boss SEO who just want native module :) tnx man

Comment: You can mark my answer if it helped, Thanks..and for native module...you can just write a service in java and connect it via bridge. There are many tutorials for that. But with that you would need to use native code for ios too.

Answer (score 1):

For Android, there's this option: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android. You could also just write native code to do what you to do. Refer to the Android guides on how to implement services.

Comment: I know that services in Android work this way, yes. By reading through the article it becomes clear that you simply define a service and start it from your JS thread. So yes, I'm pretty certain it's the right way to approach your problem.